# If cell matches any others in range copy content to "results" sheet

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

I want to check if the text in A3 matches the text in any other cells in range A5:A50.

If it does I want to copy the contents of the Y cell (with the same row number as the a cell that matched A3) into the next free cell in the A column in a sheet called results. It needs to also keep the cell colour when it copies the Y cell.

All I could get was putting this in the destination cell

```
= VLOOKUP(Sheet1!A3, Sheet1$A$5:$Y50, 25, TRUE)
```

That doesn't work as I need to run it over multiple sheets all with different names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with activesheet
   for each c in .range("A5:A50").cells
      if c.value = .range("A3").value then
         c.offset(0,24).copy _
              worksheets("results").cells(rows.count,1).end(xlup).offset(1,0) 
      end if
   next c
end with
```

Answer (score 0):

You can employ a dynamic 3d-Vlookup technique by listing the sheetnames to search in a list somewhere, naming that range of cells **MySheets** and then use a construct like this:

```
=VLOOKUP(A3, INDIRECT("'" & INDEX(MySheets, MATCH(1, COUNTIF(INDIRECT("'" & MySheets &"'!A1:A50"), A3), 0)) & "'!A:B"), 2, 0)
```

There's a sample workbook [**on my site**](https://sites.google.com/a/madrocketscientist.com/jerrybeaucaires-excelassistant/search-functions/3d-lookup) demonstrating this.